# I want to capture daily PCAP using Tcpdump using cron

Tags: bash, cron, tcpdump

I want to capture PCAP files using Tcpdump in cron (Raspberry Pi). I have written a bash file.  However, I would like to capture traffic daily in a new file and stop the older capture.  At the moment a new file is created but the older file keeps capturing

```
 #Variable
 DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
 SET_INTERFACE=eth0
 SAVE_IN_FOLDER=/media/pi/tinausb
 SAVE_AS_FILE=tcpdump_$DATE.pcap

 #Execute tcpdump command
 /usr/sbin/tcpdump -G 86400 -i $SET_INTERFACE -s0 -w        
 SAVE_IN_FOLDER/$SAVE_AS_FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   -G rotate_seconds
      If specified, rotates the dump file specified with the -w option
      every  rotate_seconds  seconds.   Savefiles  will  have the name
      specified by -w which should include a time format as defined by
      strftime(3).  If no time format is specified, each new file will
      overwrite the previous.

      If used in conjunction with the -C option, filenames  will  take
      the form of `file<count>'.
```

This means the file name you give with -w must contains the % format you pass to date. In short:

```
SAVE_AS_FILE=tcpdump_%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.pcap
```

Oh, and your question has nothing to do with Python btw.

Comment: As you can see in the bash file i already specified the time format.  I think I would need to kill the last tcpdump process as the new capture starts.  I am not capturing by size i want to capture 24 worth of traffic - new file - then this stops when the next day of capture starts

Comment: You did not specify the time format in the `SAVE_AS_FILE` because `$DATE` expands to a *specific* date, and is therefore not a date specifier.  Instead, use the format as @Tey suggested, namely: `SAVE_AS_FILE=tcpdump_%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.pcap`.